# form hidden input value disappearing with .show()

Tags: jquery, show, hidden-field

I have the following input in a form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myId" name="form-type" class="myClass" value="myValue">
```

When the page is loaded the form is hidden.  When I click the show button,

```
    $("#showButton").click( function() {
        $("#form").show();
    });
```

the value disappears.

```
<input type="hidden" id="myId" name="form-type" class="myClass" value="">
```

It is supposed to be passed to php When i click a submit button. The button is clicked and I pass myValue in $(".myClass").serialize().  Let me stress that it was working fine. I have 5 other forms in my app that work the same way and have no issues.  O yea. Even when I refresh the page, the value is still missing.  I have to cut and paste the line I shared above to a different line, then refresh the page before I can see the value again.  Has anyone seen this before.  I've been working a lot lately, so I could just be going crazy ;)

Comment: works fine here:  http://jsfiddle.net/SbGus/

Comment: Show the rest of the code, the .show isn't the problem.

Comment: You're right. It was later in the code. There was another click listener that set $(".myClass").val("");. I've just been working too late I think.  Thanks for your time guys.  Is there a way to remove a question?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the above code you have added, you're missing alot of quotes and the closing brackets for your click function. Is this the same in your live code?

```
<input type="hidden" id="myId" name="form-type" class="myClass" value="myValue">

$("#showButton").click( function() {
    $("#form").show();
});

<input type="hidden" id="myId" name="form-type" class="myClass" value="">
```

Above is with the added quotes and closing bracket.

Comment: I'm assuming he's just showing a snippet of the js, if that were the problem the .show wouldn't work.

Comment: @RickCalder I thought that might be the case too, but thought I should check anyway =)

Comment: yea. i'm afraid I was being lazy. Just did some more testing and the the value comes back on refresh now. But it's disappearing when I .show() anything.